# ValidForm Builder: Documentation for meta-parameter

Tags: validform

Almost anything that can be added to the form seems to accept a meta parameter. Unfortunately I haven't found any documentation for those. Is there any list of possible options? Where they work, what they do?

[note: question is specific about ValidFormBuilder and it is encouraged by the developers to ask Questions here this way]

Answer (score 0):

metaparams I so far have stumbled across (to be continued.. maybe..)

---

**ATTRIBUTES**

---

almost anything will turn into an attribute. With the prefix field it will become an attribute of the input, otherwise of the wrapper.

Example:

```
$form->addField(
        'test',
        'test',
        ValidForm::VFORM_STRING,
        array( ),
        array( ),
        array ( 
            'class' => 'testClass',
            'fieldClass' => 'testFieldClass',

            'data-test' => 'someTestData',
            'fielddata-test' => 'moreTestData',


            'useless' => 'pileOfJunk',
            'fielduseless' => 'jetAnotherPileOfJunk'
        )
    );
```

results in:

```
div class="testClass vf__optional" useless="pileOfJunk" data-test="someTestData">
    <label for="test">test</label>
    <input id="test" class="vf__string vf__text testFieldClass" type="text" 
           useless="jetAnotherPileOfJunk" data-test="moreTestData" name="test" value="">
</div>
```

---

**SPECIAL**

---

some seem to have special functionality though:

**start** & **end**
can sometimes define ranges. E.g.:

```
$form->addField(
        'rangeex',
        'Rangeex',
        ValidForm::VFORM_SELECT_LIST,
        array(),
        array(),
        array(
                "start" => 1,
                "end" => 3              
        )
);
```

results in:

```
<div class="vf__optional">
    <label for="rangeex">Rangeex</label>
    <select id="rangeex" class="vf__one vf__select" name="rangeex">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**tip**
??prop. tooltip.. didn't test..

**default / hint**
set a default value.. when using hint, the hint itself doesn't pass validation for req. fields. (not sure if / where that actually works, neither default nor hint add a default value to a select for example, though hint can still be used to make the validation fail if an option with the same value is selected)